# Lift Cookbook Avoiding CSS and JavaScript Caching

Tags: css, scala, lift

I am trying to use the data-lift="with-resource-id" parameter to the  tag as described in the Lift Cookbook (http://cookbook.liftweb.net/#AvoidAssetCaching) to avoid asset caching in the browser. I've copied the code sample provided in the cookbook and modified it to my environment in order to introduce a random value into the parameter path.

My assets are stored in two root directories -- one called "css" and one called "js" for css and javascript respectively.

My code looks like:

```
import net.liftweb.http._
import net.liftweb.util._

object AssetCacheBuster {

  def init() : Unit = {
    val resourceId = Helpers.nextFuncName

    LiftRules.attachResourceId = (path: String) => {
      val PathRegex = """\/cached(\/css\/|\/js\/)(\S+)""".r
      try {
        val PathRegex(root, rest) = path
        "/cached" + root + resourceId + "/" + rest
      } catch {
        case e: scala.MatchError => path
      }
    }

    // Remove the cache/{resourceId} from the request if there is one

    LiftRules.statelessRewrite.prepend( NamedPF("BrowserCacheAssist") {
      case RewriteRequest(ParsePath("cached" :: "css" :: id :: file :: Nil, suffix, _, _), _, _) =>
    RewriteResponse("css" :: file :: Nil, suffix)
      case RewriteRequest(ParsePath("js" :: id :: file :: Nil, suffix, _, _), _, _) =>
        RewriteResponse("js" :: file :: Nil, suffix)
    })    
  }
}
```

I embed the css files, for example, with a call like:

```
<link  data-lift="with-resource-id" rel="stylesheet" type="text/css" href="/cached/css/standard.css" />
```

The way I expect it to work is that attachResourceId logic will recognize embedded css files by the path "/cached/css" and inject a unique value in the path. So, for example, /cached/css/standard.css becomes /cached/css/F7017951738702RYSX0/standard.css. By inspecting elements using Chrome, I can see that this is indeed occurring, so I believe this is working as expected.

In the rewriting logic at the bottom, I expect it to look for requests that start with "/cached/css" and remove the /cached and unique id components. By tracing in the debugger, this too seems to be working. In the debugger I can see the the resulting url it is trying to rewrite is "/css/standard.css". And I can verify that if I enter this value in my browser URL, that content does indeed get served. Yet, the browser is showing an error (which I can see via Chrome's console) that the .css file is not found.

Answer (score 2):

**Here's what I think you're seeing...**

Typically Lift will ignore CSS and JS files, and they will be served by the underlying engine, such as Jetty or Tomcat. That all happens outside of the Lift.

In this case, the end result of the rewrite is (as an example) a request for */css/standard.css*, which is correct. But that final resource is being resolved inside Lift (because that's where we are -- the re-writes aren't HTTP redirects, so we stay inside the Lift pipeline). And because Lift doesn't serve those files by default, you're seeing a 404.

This is also why */css/standard.css* works for you directly in a browser, because Lift is ignoring the request and Tomcat (or similar) is serving the content.

So why does it work in the book example? In that case, the example is for */classpath/jquery.js*, and that URL is something Lift knows how to serve (via `ResourceServer`).

**Here's what you can do about it....**

I'd say the simple solution is to teach Lift how to serve up these files. You can do that by matching on the path you care about, and streaming back the content:

```
LiftRules.statelessDispatch.append {
  case Req("css" :: file :: Nil, "css", _) =>
    () => for (in <- LiftRules.getResource("/css/"+file+".css").map(_.openStream)) 
       yield {
        StreamingResponse(in, () => in.close, size = -1,
          headers = Nil,  cookies = Nil, code=200)
      }
}
```

The same applies for the JS files, so you can probably generalise that code a little, or adjust to your needs. There's a [chapter on streaming content in the Cookbook](http://cookbook.liftweb.net/#RestStreamContent).

If that works for you, let me know, and I'll update the book.

As an aside, you might get more eyeballs on the problem if [you post to the Lift mailing list](http://cookbook.liftweb.net/#GettingHelp).  Don't get me wrong: I totally love Stackoverflow, but just due to the history of Lift, the mailing list is where you find users and committers looking at questions and problems.

Comment: This solved the issue I was having when I tried to implement something similar. However, since the rewrite in the book is for all file types, I needed to modify it a bit to only work with certain extensions. I created a Gist with what ended up working for me: https://gist.github.com/jcern/6274003 if it is helpful. It uses the rewrite for extensions that are specified, and defaults to the query parameter method for those that don't. Only other issue, which can't be avoided, is that doing the rewrite on a css file breaks any relative paths, like: `background-image : url(../images/file.png)`.

Answer (score 1):

Do you really need this complex logic?

By default, lift's resources will look like `/static/css/example.css?F745187285965AXEHTY=_`. In this case, if you use either nginx / jetty / tomcat / embedded jetty, you'll just see everything working.

The reason of that is that jetty/tomcat/nginx take the main resource `example.css` instead of `example.css?asdfadf=_` if they can't find the latter. And the resource with `?asdfasdf=_` *will* be cached by the browser. So, the browser remembers the content of the full css address.

This is a common technique to avoid caching, BTW. It's not only Lift related. By default, developers update resources and write some HTML like:  `/static/css/example.css?14` where `14` is the virtual version of the resource. This way they don't have to rename the resource itself.

Comment: For now, I've implemented the approach you recommend. That said, I was striving to implement this complex logic because, at least according to the lift cookbook text: "Note that some proxies may choose not to cache resources with query parameters at all. If that impacts you, it’s possible to code a custom resource ID method to move the random resource ID out of the query parameter and into the path." Several of our customers do use proxy servers, and I was hoping to create a solution that would work well for them as well.

Comment: well, in this case the caching proxy will have additional load, but the client-s browsers will cache the resource anyway. So, the caching proxy will be less powerfull, but everything will work anyway. Don't know about others, but personally I'd call it absolutely acceptable.

Comment: In the scenario that you describe, the concern I have is that if the proxy server ignores the additional parameter, then there is no way to force the browser to reload the assets when they change. Right, or am I missing something in what you said?

Comment: well, but your qoute says otherwise: "some proxies may choose not to cache resources". So, the proxy will not cache. So the browser will get always new content, and it can cache by itself.

Comment: Good point. I've read that several times and misinterpreted it each time. I guess I'll go with the simpler approach for now until I see that it causes a problem. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You need to inject the random value as a GET value not a path. Changing the path would result in not finding the file (unless you are dynamically writing the css file every time to the random location).

This can be done inline with javascript.

```
<script>
document.write("<link rel=\"stylesheet\"type=\"text/css\" href=\"/cached/css/standard.css?" + Math.random() + "\" />");
</script>
```

Comment: he is using Lift to do request rewriting so the request to `/cached/css/F7017951738702RYSX0/standard.css` should get served correctly from the `/css/standard.css` location on the disk. Though your solution would also achieve a similar result.

Comment: ah thanks, sorry I'm not familiar with the lift frame work. if its just a couple of css and js files in the header though this will be an easy fix for the problem